# Redo merge of just a single file

Tags: git, merge

I'm in the middle of a large merge, and I've used `git mergetool` to resolve all the conflicts, but I have not committed yet, as I wanted to make sure the merge was ok first.

It turns out that I made a mistake while resolving the conflicts in one file, and I would like to redo the conflict resolution with `git mergetool` on that file. As this is a large merge I would like to avoid redoing the merge on all the other files, as I understand I would have to do with `git merge --abort`.

I know I could just edit the file manually, but this would be quite tedious and it would be much easier to just redo the `git mergetool` operation. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-merge a file in the git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434995/how-to-re-merge-a-file-in-the-git)

Answer (score 217, accepted):

It seems I was just looking in the wrong place. The solution turned out to be quite simple.

```
git checkout -m <file>
```

This returns the file to its conflicted state. I can then run `git mergetool` to redo the merge.

Comment: This sort of worked for me.  The index ended up in a merged state, but mergetool did not think that there were any outstanding merges.  I just did the merge using vi, but it was weird anyway.

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what is needed. By the way, manual merging with vi is always a pleasure and fully satisfying. shifting to left or shifting to right never gave me the confidence that the merge is going as expected

Comment: There are some helpful additional details (with the same answer) in [this duplicate question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435230/411282).

Answer (score -4):

You can always edit the files manually.

If you are using the `git merge --no-commit`, then you will simply have a prepared commit (after the auto and semi-auto) merge.

You can still safely edit the files and only commit when completely satisfied.