# Correct merged file in git

Tags: git, git-merge

I performed a merge of two branches, resolved the conflicts with mergetool, and confirmed that the all the files have been merged. So now all the files are staged for commit

Trying to compile though, I found that there is something broken in a specific file.

How can I run the mergetool again for a specific file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to re-merge a file in the git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434995/how-to-re-merge-a-file-in-the-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redo merge of just a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857082/redo-merge-of-just-a-single-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
git checkout -m -- file
```

This will bring back the file to the conflicted or unmerged state and you can resolve it again.